# Java Jersey JSON webservice proper array return

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I currently have a webservice that returns this JSON:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "description":"RGB LED module"
   },
   {  
      "id":4,
      "description":"Motion Sensor module"
   },
   {  
      "id":3,
      "description":"Camera module"
   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "description":"Display module"
   }
]
```

However, I need it to be:

```
{  
   "modules":[  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "description":"RGB LED module"
      },
      {  
         "id":4,
         "description":"Motion Sensor module"
      },
      {  
         "id":3,
         "description":"Camera module"
      },
      {  
         "id":2,
         "description":"Display module"
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I achieve this?

This is my current Java code:

```
  @GET
  @Path("availableModules")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response getModules()
  {        
     return Response.ok(createAvailableModuleList()) //200
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")
        .build();
  }
```

createAvailableModuleList returns a mocked ArrayList for now, and looks like this:

```
  public List<Module> createAvailableModuleList()
  {
    Module ledModule=new Module(1, "RGB LED module");
    Module motionSensorModule=new Module(4, "Motion Sensor module");
    Module cameraModule=new Module(3, "Camera module");
    Module displayModule=new Module(2, "Display module");

    List<Module> modules = new ArrayList<Module>();
    modules.add(ledModule);
    modules.add(motionSensorModule);
    modules.add(cameraModule);
    modules.add(displayModule);
    return modules;
  }
```

Comment: One way I can think of is to create class in which you assign Module list to.

Comment: How would that look like? A class with only the list of modules? And return the class in the response?

Comment: Yes, exactly how you described it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the list in a map with one entry

```
 LinkedHashMap<String,Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
 map.put("modules", createAvailableModuleList()); 
 return Response.ok(map)...
```

Comment: this is even a better idea

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks mate!